# How get enviroment varible or CloudFormation info in Resolver mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I have request mapping template for BatchGetItem

```
{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "user-post": { ## Get table name from enviroment varible  or CloudFormation
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}
```

and response `$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.user-post)`. How I can get table name automatical from enviroment varible or CloudFormation, to not write manually it. My mapping template has Data source `user-post` - dynamoDB table.

Comment: Can you please explain the usecase you are trying to solve? Are you creating AppSync resources using a CloudFormation template?

Comment: @ShankarRaju I have GraphQL schema and dynamoDB table. I want get all user post. User has array of ids of post. I use sub query for it. All works fine,  but I want to insert name of table auto. (get it from somewhere). Because I have several stack and when I deploy it I need change name of table for each stack manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying the resolver (and mapping templates) to AppSync via a CloudFormation, you should be able to use a reference to populate the DynamoDB table name automatically.

If you are creating a DynamoDB table in the same cloudformation template, then the return output of the DynamoDB cloudformation entry will be the table name and you can reference that.

Here is the documentation for creating a DynamoDB table with cloudformation and what the return output is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#w2ab2c21c10d384c15

Here is the documentation for using "Ref" to refer to a resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html

If your DynamoDB table is created beforehand, you could pass the table name in via a cloudformation stack parameter or inside a map, and then you can reference it.

You may have to use "Ref" in conjunction with some of the other Cloudformation helper functions, such as "Sub" to substitute the DynamoDB table reference into your mapping template definition.

Example of using Sub and Ref combined: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab2c21c28c59c11

Comment: Your reply does not resolve the problem, because the the resolver template don't get the name on BatchGetItem, specially because in BatchGetItem we can use multiple tables.